# Dashboard in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, performancepoint, ootb, dashboard, kpi

I need to create some dashboards in SharePoint Online (with OOB or any feature provided by MSFT), I am not allowed to use any kind of Custom Code for it. As Performance Point is not available in SPO, I am stuck.
Any suggestion how would I achieve it!

Note: Data is in SharePoint list.

Comment: I just come to know about Power-view,  is it presented in SharePoint online to create dashboards!

Comment: You probably mean [Power-BI](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Power-BI-Overview-and-Learning-02730e00-5c8c-4fe4-9d77-46b955b71467?ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU), which is an additional product from Microsoft and [you have to pay for it](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/powerBI/pricing.aspx), it can visualize data **from** SharePoint but has nothing to do with SharePoint

Comment: What kind of data do you want to display in your dashboard?

Comment: @Danny... I am talking about the MSFT reporting tool Power-View that is part of Power BI. I was thinking to create dashboard in Power-view and then publishing it on SPO.  By-the-way I have Power BI license also can I achieve something, I desire, with it !

Comment: @Louis...  it is the data from Info-Path Form, it contains Text, Integer and alpha numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that your data is in SharePoint Lists, and on dashboard you would want to show some latest items from them. You have options like:

- **Content Query WebPart**: The Content Query Web Part is a powerful tool that can be used to roll up data and aggregate content from `SharePoint lists`, `libraries`, `Site`, or `Site Collection`. [Check on how to use the Content Query Web Part to Rollup Data](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/05/10/how-to-use-the-content-query-web-part-to-rollup-data-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)
- **Content By Search WebPart**: It displays search results in a way that you can easily format. Each Content Search Web Part is associated with a search query and shows the results for that search query. Get more information from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163789.aspx) and [Chris'O Brien's Blog](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/10/using-content-search-web-part-and.html)
- **Custom Views**: You can create custom views of list and library. You can use views to see the items in a list or library that are most important to you or that fit a particular purpose. For example, you can create views of the files in a library that apply to a specific department or the items in a list that were created by a specific person. Check [What are SharePoint views? Learn how to use and create them](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/what-is-a-sharepoint-view-and-how-to-use-it) and [Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)

Also it is **very important** to know [When to use the Content Query Web Part or the Content Search Web Part in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/When-to-use-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-or-the-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929)

Comment: Asad.. I guess you interpret my question in some sense for VIEWs in SharePoint. I am actually looking for Dashboards (pie charts and Bar Graphs etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Although you wrote you cannot use any kind of Custom Code and might already know, if you are allowed to use Javascript, you can display listview as chart.

http://www.sites.se/2013/12/sharepoint-online-charts-office-365/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've tried to do : Javascript code to show charts, but since you said without custom code, that's not an option, so the other way is Power BI. I've tested it on my tickets list page and it looks fine, it can query Sharepoint lists. However, here are a few negative points : no real time update (or at least I don't know how to do it), so you have to update the file manually by pressing the update data button; I didn't find the way to change titles in the charts (I read that would come in next updates). [image]

Comment: your dashboard is very nice.. can you share your Java script codes. I'll keep it for future use [where customer can allow codes ;) ]

Comment: Hi @cjs, it's not Javascript, it's an Excel sheet made with Power BI. However, I also managed to do charts with Javascript, which was quite difficult. I'll try to post something in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

The best possible solution would be using google chart api or other third party chart api's which can be used at client side via content editor web parts.

SharePoint online offer's JSOM based api which you can easily integrated with google chart api for mapping the list as data source.

Personally, I have tried this many times in earlier SharePoint versions and it is very intuitive and handy. The only thing you need to learn is its methods/properties for populating specific charts

Pls refer the below reference links:

[Link-1](https://sudhirke.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/building-sharepoint-dashboards-with-google-chart/)

[Link-2](http://www.sharepointblue.com/2010/04/intractive-sharepoint-charts-with-no.html)

[Link-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574451/google-charts-using-sharepoint-list-data)